# How can I tokenize a string with a lot of different characters?

Tags: android, stringtokenizer

I want to split a string that looks like this:

```
Johannesburg General Hospital011 488 4911
```

But some of the strings have a space in between like this:

```
Johannesburg General Hospital 011 488 4911
```

I want it to be it 2 different arrays like this:

Johannesburg General Hospital

and

011 488 4911

How do I split if there is no space?

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. Please add an example of what would be the result of the tokenization of the string you show in the question.

Comment: are you getting the data from an XML?

Comment: Some more information about the source data would be good, to see if there are any rules applicable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could build a regular expression for this but a `for` cycle will do just as good:

```
/**
* @return the rest of the input text from the first digit
*/
public String findPhone(String text) {
    for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); ++i) {
        if (Character.isDigit(text.charAt(i))) {
            return text.substring(i);
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

And you can call it like:

```
String number = findPhone("Johannesburg General Hospital011 488 4911")
// number is 011 488 4911 here
String sanitizedNumber = number.replace(" ", ""); // number without spaces
```

Comment: Your the first one here who understands what I am trying to ask!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use groups with regular expressions, this could be your expression.

```
 Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([^\\d]*) ([\\d ]*)");
       //  get a matcher object
       Matcher m = p.matcher("Johannesburg General Hospital 011 488 4911 Johannesburg General Hospital 011 488 4911");
       int count = 0;
       while(m.find()) {
           count++;
           System.out.println(m.group(1));
           System.out.println(m.group(2));
      }
   }
```

Thanks

Comment: Java has the split() method that accepts a regular expression. One can say: myString.split("&nbsp;|Police") and the &nbsp and Police words will be used as tokenizers. But the question does not contain the expected result and the explanation is too blurry.